# How to refer to child class type in function parameters in php8?

Tags: php, inheritance, php-8

Let's say I have 3 classes. 1 parent and 2 children. Car has beforeSaving method

```
class Car
{
    /**
     * @param mixed $resource
     */
    protected function beforeSaving($resource)
    {
    }
}

class Audi extends Car
{
}

class Toyota extends Car
{
}
```

Now I want to create a function in Car class, that would take the given child Class as a parameter. I could just leave it without type or throw mixed there. But is there any way I could throw something like "self" as a parameter type and it would refer to Audi, when called inside Audi class and Toyota, when called inside Toyota?

I would like that beforeSaving() is typed in each class so it would not accept Toyota as a parameter in Audi class. I know self does not work as it refers to Car in Audi and Toyota. But is there way to refer to class extending the Car?

```
class Car
{
    protected function beforeSaving(self $resource)
    {
    }
}

class Audi extends Car
{
    protected function beforeSaving(Audi $resource)
    {
    }
}

class Toyota extends Car
{
    protected function beforeSaving(Toyota $resource)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example (code) of what it is exactly you'd like to achieve?

Comment: It could be pseudo code that's ok, it is just to understand your goal since your question can be interpreted in many ways

Comment: I've written some real code from your pseudo-code, but feel free to revert it if I messed something. The strange part here is that a class needs to receive its child subclasses as parameter. You can either create an interface or use `Car` (or `self`) as type, but the purpose of the overall design is very unclear.

Comment: I have added an example, what I would like to achieve. It does not work like this, but thats what I'd like to achieve.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.variance.php